# How to make a game over sequence for tic tac toe when there are no winners?

Tags: if-statement, button, label

I would like to display a label that says game over when there are no winners. I just thought to make an else statement but once there is one click game over would be display since the elif statements are false. Any ideas.

```
from tkinter import*

#Window stuff   
window = Tk()
window.title("Tic Tac Toe")
window.configure(background = "black")
window.geometry("400x400")

#Variables
global clickable
playerXturn = True
ticker = 0 

#Display X or O
def buttonClicked(c) : 
    global playerXturn
    if playerXturn == True :
        buttonList[c]["image"] = picX
        buttonList[c]["state"] = DISABLED
        playerXturn = False
        labelTurn ["text"] = "O's turn"

    elif clickable[c] == "" : 
        buttonList[c]["image"] = picO
        buttonList[c]["state"] = DISABLED
        playerXturn = True
        labelTurn ["text"] = "X's turn"
#Info for user
    global ticker
    ticker += 1
    if ticker == 500 :
        labelInfo["text"] = "Timed Out"
        labelInfo["bg"] = "red" 


#Three in a row
    elif (button1["image"] == str(picX) and button2["image"] == str(picX) and button3["image"] == str(picX) or
          button4["image"] == str(picX) and button5["image"] == str(picX) and button6["image"] == str(picX) or
          button7["image"] == str(picX) and button8["image"] == str(picX) and button9["image"] == str(picX) or
          button1["image"] == str(picX) and button4["image"] == str(picX) and button7["image"] == str(picX) or
          button2["image"] == str(picX) and button5["image"] == str(picX) and button8["image"] == str(picX) or
          button3["image"] == str(picX) and button6["image"] == str(picX) and button9["image"] == str(picX) or
          button1["image"] == str(picX) and button5["image"] == str(picX) and button9["image"] == str(picX) or
          button3["image"] == str(picX) and button5["image"] == str(picX) and button7["image"] == str(picX)) :
        #print ("X") 
        labelInfo["text"] = "X Wins"
        labelInfo["bg"] = "red"
        button1["state"] = DISABLED
        button2["state"] = DISABLED
        button3["state"] = DISABLED
        button4["state"] = DISABLED
        button5["state"] = DISABLED
        button6["state"] = DISABLED
        button7["state"] = DISABLED
        button8["state"] = DISABLED
        button9["state"] = DISABLED
        labelTurn ["bg"] = "black" 

    elif (button1["image"] == str(picO) and button2["image"] == str(picO) and button3["image"] == str(picO) or
          button4["image"] == str(picO) and button5["image"] == str(picO) and button6["image"] == str(picO) or
          button7["image"] == str(picO) and button8["image"] == str(picO) and button9["image"] == str(picO) or
          button1["image"] == str(picO) and button4["image"] == str(picO) and button7["image"] == str(picO) or
          button2["image"] == str(picO) and button5["image"] == str(picO) and button8["image"] == str(picO) or
          button3["image"] == str(picO) and button6["image"] == str(picO) and button9["image"] == str(picO) or
          button1["image"] == str(picO) and button5["image"] == str(picO) and button9["image"] == str(picO) or
          button3["image"] == str(picO) and button5["image"] == str(picO) and button7["image"] == str(picO)) :
        #print("O") 
        labelInfo["text"] = "O Wins"
        labelInfo["bg"] = "red"
        button1["state"] = DISABLED
        button2["state"] = DISABLED
        button3["state"] = DISABLED
        button4["state"] = DISABLED
        button5["state"] = DISABLED
        button6["state"] = DISABLED
        button7["state"] = DISABLED
        button8["state"] = DISABLED
        button9["state"] = DISABLED
        labelTurn ["bg"] = "black"  

#Images
picX = PhotoImage (file = "x.gif") 
picO = PhotoImage (file = "o.gif")
picBlank = PhotoImage (file = "sw.gif") 

#Buttons
button1 = Button (window, text = "", image = picBlank, command = lambda: buttonClicked(0))     
button1.grid (row = 0, column = 0)
#button1["state"] = DISABLED 
button2 = Button (window, text = "", image = picBlank, command = lambda: buttonClicked(1))    
button2.grid (row = 0, column = 1)
#button2["state"] = DISABLED 
button3 = Button (window, text = "", image = picBlank, command = lambda: buttonClicked(2))  
button3.grid (row = 0, column = 2)
#button3["state"] = DISABLED 
button4 = Button (window, text = "", image = picBlank, command = lambda: buttonClicked(3))   
button4.grid (row = 1, column = 0)
#button4["state"] = DISABLED 
button5 = Button (window, text = "", image = picBlank,  command = lambda: buttonClicked(4)) 
button5.grid (row = 1, column = 1)
#button5["state"] = DISABLED 
button6 = Button (window, text = "", image = picBlank,  command = lambda: buttonClicked(5))  
button6.grid (row= 1, column = 2)
#button6["state"] = DISABLED 
button7 = Button (window, text = "", image = picBlank, command = lambda: buttonClicked(6)) 
button7.grid (row = 2, column = 0)
#button7["state"] = DISABLED 
button8 = Button (window, text = "", image = picBlank, command = lambda: buttonClicked(7))   
button8.grid (row = 2, column = 1)
#button8["state"] = DISABLED 
button9 = Button (window, text = "", image = picBlank, command = lambda: buttonClicked(8))  
button9.grid (row = 2, column = 2)
#button9["state"] = DISABLED 

#Lists
buttonList = [button1, button2, button3, button4, button5, button6, button7, button8, button9]
clickable = ["", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""]

#Reset
def processReset():
    button1["state"] = NORMAL
    button2["state"] = NORMAL
    button3["state"] = NORMAL
    button4["state"] = NORMAL
    button5["state"] = NORMAL
    button6["state"] = NORMAL
    button7["state"] = NORMAL
    button8["state"] = NORMAL
    button9["state"] = NORMAL
    button1["image"] = picBlank
    button2["image"] = picBlank
    button3["image"] = picBlank
    button4["image"] = picBlank
    button5["image"] = picBlank
    button6["image"] = picBlank
    button7["image"] = picBlank
    button8["image"] = picBlank
    button9["image"] = picBlank
    labelTurn["bg"] = "white"
    labelInfo["text"] = "Continue Playing"
    labelInfo["bg"] = "white" 

#Extra labels and buttons
labelMenu = Label (window, text = "Menu and Info", height = 2, width = 24, bg = "yellow") 
labelMenu.grid (row = 4, column = 4) 
labelTurn = Label (window, text = "X goes first", height = 2, width = 10)  
labelTurn.grid (row = 6, column = 4)
labelInfo = Label (window, text = "Continue Playing", height = 2, width = 14)     
labelInfo.grid (row = 5, column = 4)
buttonReset = Button(window, text = "Reset/New Game", bg = "Orange", command = processReset)  
buttonReset.grid (row = 7, column = 4) 
labelNote = Label (window, text = "Note: Losing player goes first next game", bg = "Pink") 
labelNote.grid (row = 8, column = 4) 
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: set a flag to indicate the game was won, and then a separate `if` aftewrards `if (all moves done and not won) { everyone loses/tie }`

Answer (score 0):

You want an `elif` statement at the end of your else-if chain that checks whether there's any empty spaces left. If there's no spaces left, and a winner wasn't declared by one of the statements before this one, it's necessarily a tie.

Something like:

```
elif (check that no empty board spaces remain) :
#print("-")
labelInfo["text"] = "It's a tie!"
```

Comment: You gave me an idea, what I did was made a variable that was set to true when a game was one and then I had a nested if statement where after 9 clicks and the variable being false it would change a label to "Its a tie".